# Counting value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Pandas made like this:

```
name   domain   rank1   rank2   rank3   ...   rank_mean

foo    foo.com  1       1       2       ...   1.34
boo    boo.it   5       12              ...   6.4
test   test.eu          2       2       ...   2.6
```

The column name and domain represent the site name and his url, columns "rank" is their position in certain list in a certain period. For example rank1 mean all the website present in my list from `01-02-2019` to `28-02-2019`, rank2 goes from `01-03-2019` to `31-03-2019` and so on (dateformat dd-mm-yyyy).
Some values could be void maybe because in rank1 period the website `test.eu` doesn't exist and was created later, or `boo.it` it no longer exist after rank2.

I want a list with the count value of each `rank` column.
I've tried with:
`df.count()` but it return all the columns like this

```
name      3
domain    3
rank1     2
rank2     3
rank3     2
.
.
.
rank_mean 3
```

but i want only the columns named "rank", like this:

```
rank1  2
rank2  3
rank3  2
```

I've tried also `df.count(rank_list)` with `rank_list = ["rank1", "rank2", "rank3", ...]` but return me this error: `unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, if you have the list `rank_list` already, is to use `index.isin`:

```
rank_list = ["rank1", "rank2", "rank3"]
qwe= df2.count()
qwe[qwe.index.isin(rank_list)]
```

Ouput:

```
rank1    2
rank2    3
rank3    2
dtype: int64
```

Another option is to use `str.contains` (if you don't have the rank_list):

```
qwe= df2.count()
qwe[qwe.index.str.contains('rank')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this work pretty well for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use a column filter before calling count:

```py
import re

df[[col for col in df if re.match('rank\d+', col) ]].count()
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('rank\d+')].count()` is another option similar to your solution.

Comment: `df.filter(regex=r'rank\d+').count()`

Comment: @mozway Thanks for suggesting `filter`. It's a method I under use!

Comment: Thank you, this is ok but don't work properly with my issue, with the RE also the last column named "rank_mean" would be counted.

Comment: @gianlucagabriele it won't. Have you tried it? My regex purposely rejects `rank_mean` or anything that is not `rank` plus digits. No problem with you going for the other working solution though.